# flutter card render overflow issue

Tags: flutter, gridview, layout

I have a grid view and I keep getting this over flow problem on the column. I have no idea how to fix this and tried as many ways as i can find.

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => {print('clicked')},
                    child: Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 6, 6, 6),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(4.5),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(4.5),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
                                bottomRight: Radius.zero,
                              ),
                              child: Image.network(
                                prop.thumbnail,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 100,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.orange,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 6, 0, 6),
                                  child: Text(
                                    prop.description,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text('text'),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text('text'),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 9,
                                  child: Text('text'),,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.audiotrack,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    size: 30.0,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Can you share screenshot of this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Its a private project for a client. It just says Bottom overflowed by 20px. But i've tried commenting out everything and just used loads of text() in the column and it still happenes. The error says the issue is on the Column. At first I wasn't sure if it was on the grid view item, or card. really not sure

Comment: Can you share a code with the GridView as well?

Comment: put every widget in Column and Rows in Expanded widget, and decrease/increase the child aspect ratio in GridView's SliverDelegate

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue you're having is one of two things... (but probably the second one below)

1. You have a fixed height of 100 for your picture.  Try cutting that down to 80 and see if that makes up for it.  If so, this is something that you will need to account for. I created this dartpad to test out that theory: https://dartpad.dev/216440eee06d8fde3ef63f3845026946
2. I'm assuming that you have a long list of 'text' widgets that is going off the screen.  if this is the case, you can wrap the Column in a **SingleChildScrollView** so that it can scroll off the page.  I created an example of that here:
   https://dartpad.dev/cc724a72283b7b01cfd992fe80da5eb4

Comment: This did work but not really what I was looking for. I am looking for an item which height will scale according to its childrens height.

Comment: I recommend reading this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know-edc9516d1a2 What you're asking is not preferred.  Perhaps look at one of these method: 1) IntrinsicHeight widget, seen here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html 2) LayoutBuilder or 3) MeasuredSize package https://pub.dev/packages/measured_size  Some of these are discussed in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66610141/flutter-card-render-overflow-issue/66610343?noredirect=1#comment117753146_66610343 Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look through those and try to fix it and then i will post my results if i can fix it

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code please try this and let me know.

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => {print('clicked')},
          child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 6, 6, 6),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(4.5),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(4.5),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
                      bottomRight: Radius.zero,
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(
                      prop.thumbnail,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 6, 0, 6),
                        child: Text(
                          prop.description,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('text'),
                  Text('text'),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 9,
                        child: Text('text'),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.audiotrack,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help. but thank you for you effort